# Different Phone sizes not letting me authenticate in Spotify Web API on IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, spotify

I am currently trying to work with the spotify web API on a mobile app that I am developing and I thought everything was going fine because I was testing the app and everything was working. I was using the iPhone 14 Pro simulator. I then tried to plug in my personal phone to build the app onto it (iPhone 13 Pro Max) and it wasn't working so I tried to run it on the simulator for the iPhone 14 Pro max and everything still crashed.

The problem that I am running into is that for some reason the query items from the Redirect URL is not the same for both devices. This is the function that I am using to extract the query items:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    
    
    //print(self.codeVerifier)
        
        if url.absoluteString.starts(with: redirectURI) {
            if let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
               let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems {
                // Extract the authorization code from the query items
                var code: String?
                for item in queryItems {
                    if item.name == "code" {
                        code = item.value
                        break
                    }
                }
                print(queryItems)
                
                // Verify the code verifier
                if let code = code, let storedCodeVerifier = self.codeVerifier, verifyCodeVerifier(storedCodeVerifier) {
                    requestAccessToken(code: code)
                    signOutButton.isHidden = false
                    displayDataButton.isHidden = false
                }
                
                print("hi")
                
                webView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

When I print the query items on the iPhone 14, I get something that looks like this which is what I expect:

> [code=AQDYBJnCNU7O17gFSog0aUvM3LjjigPQAMQLDE8q7ucdAZo7arEw1rxdJcysAB7gxhuT_2szj8z6XvnJnsaGomUt0YgvpkGjTnq_Gjr6TMScWmPxlHgPg4Bwy-iflCFq8_gYZlTXjy-WokNjRq0FYmvgVbDcM14c8fqMQ8G32IZnDxfO8GQbcN1bUuSNOVTgrTWvmQOKThHVWiIpOSbAf3hc_CuZvKzBurOi-Rv5KTgGSVKbnWa_tv42JtVpyckDOGkT-z0Wnhyj1Ig8c8jhVEvbcK43fkdDQQMD59aPZ0PPj_0rkBFtGowVxvE]

But when I print the query items on the iPhone 14 max, I get something that looks like this:

> [ar=1, k=6LfCVLAUAAAAALFwwRnnCJ12DalriUGbj8FW_J39,
> co=aHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5zcG90aWZ5LmNvbTo0NDM., hl=en,
> v=khH7Ei3klcvfRI74FvDcfuOo, size=invisible, cb=dxrrvlwvv8sx]

What could possibly be going wrong?